# Find Average and Minimum Value from Array Object - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data like below,

```
resultFromCalculation = [{'value40': {'A': 3.1, 'B': 5.62, 'C': 5.99, 'D': 5.06, 'E': 5.09}}, 
    {'value50': {'A': 2.95, 'B': 5.21, 'C': 5.41, 'D': 4.64, 'E': 4.5}}, 
    {'value60': {'A': 2.35, 'B': 4.8, 'C': 4.83, 'D': 4.08, 'E': 3.62}},
    {'value70': {'A': 2.95, 'B': 5.21, 'C': 5.41, 'D': 4.64, 'E': 4.5}}]
```

I want to find average for A to E values for each list. Like,

```
avgValues = [{'value40':4.97},{'value50':4.41},{'value60':3.99},{'value70':3.99}]
```

From the above OP I need to find out which one is first least value than others.

```
FinalResultIs = value60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas:

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in resultFromCalculation], axis=1).mean()
value40    4.972
value50    4.542
value60    3.936
value70    4.542
dtype: float64

>>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in resultFromCalculation], axis=1).mean().argmin()
'value60'
```

Using simple list comprehension, you can use

```
avgValues = [{list(d.keys())[0]: sum(list(d.values())[0].values()) / len(list(d.values())[0].values())} for d in resultFromCalculation]
>>> avgValues
[{'value40': 4.9719999999999995},
 {'value50': 4.542},
 {'value60': 3.936000000000001},
 {'value70': 4.542}]
```

To find the minimum:

```
>>> min(avgValues, key=lambda e: list(e.values())[0])
{'value60': 3.936000000000001}
```

Comment: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in resultFromCalculation], axis=1).mean().argmin(). This one is Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: But I am seeing that "FutureWarning: 'argmin' is deprecated".

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
L = [pd.DataFrame(x).mean().to_dict() for x in resultFromCaluclation]
print (L)
[{'value40': 4.9719999999999995}, {'value50': 4.542}, {'value60': 3.936000000000001}, {'value70': 4.542}]
```